# how to make chained ssh work with git

Tags: ssh, firewall, git

I am trying to get round a silly firewall issue. I am trying to chain ssh access to git through a proxy ssh:

~/git-chain:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh hosticangetto ssh $*
# End
```

And then:

```
$ export GIT_SSH=~/git-chain
$ git clone ssh://git@somerepostore.com/somerepo.git

E, [2012-02-07T12:50:21.434913 #28359] ERROR -- : git command not recognized
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

the arguments being passed into my script are:

```
git@somerepostore.com git-upload-pack 'somerepo.git'
```

I've checked the keys from the hosticangetto to the git repository store and everything is ok.

I am not sure why this fails. I've done this sort of thing with mercurial before with mercurial -e switch.

Answer (score 4):

Add these lines to your `~/.ssh/config` (or create that file with these lines if it doesn't already exist):

```
Host somerepostore.com
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hosticangetto
```

Then unset GIT_SSH.

This tells ssh to ssh using hosticangetto as a proxy.  This is better than your solution because in your solution, the packets are decrypted on hosticangetto and then re-encrypted for somerepostore.com on the remote host.  Using a proxycommand like this means that packets are encrypted for somerepostore.com on your local machine and these encrypted packets are passed through hosticangetto.

Comment: using ssh proxies does work... but GIT_SSH should work too. Anyway, you're right. Proxy does work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something with the TTY.

This didn't work:

`ssh server1 ssh server2`

It just hangs there.

This seems to have worked:

`ssh -t server1 ssh server2`

Looking at the verbose output with `ssh -v server1 ssh server2` it looks like the first/outside ssh completes and I get to server1, but I do not execute the inside/second ssh for server2.

Comment: No, I don't think so. chained ssh works fine. I'm not sure what issue you're seeing. I've tried adding tty switches and it makes no difference. It would be pretty wierd if git required a tty to operate.